# Error writing Excel workbook from memory to a file. No Series?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, charts, worksheet

I'm trying to create an excel workbook with multiple worksheets. I keep getting an error **Chart1 must contain at least one data series. See chart.add_series()** I've been reading pandas excel documentation online for some time and I've read the posts in stackoverflow, but I can't seem to solve this problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                {
                    "Video": cr_dst_list,
                    "Timestamp": cr_ts_list,
                    "CP": cr_cp_list,
                    "Raw Filesize": cr_raw_fsize_list,
                    "Encoded Filesize" : cr_enc_fsize_list,
                    "CR": cr_compression_ratio_list,
                    "MSSSIM": vq_msssim_list
                }
            )
 
    last_row = max_profile + 1

    # Create Excel workbook
    excel_file = f'{dst_path}profile_analysis.xlsx'
    writer =  pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file)

    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
    for vid in cr_dst_list:
        df_vid = df.loc[df['Video'] == vid]
        #df_vid = df_vid.drop(columns=[0])
        df_vid = df_vid.drop(columns=[ 'Video', 'Timestamp', 'Raw Filesize', 'Encoded Filesize' ])

        # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object
        df_vid.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=vid) 

        # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[vid]

        # Create a chart object
        chart = workbook.add_chart( {'type': 'scatter'} )

        # Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data
        series = f'=vid!$C$2:$C${last_row+1}'
        chart.add_series({
            'values': '=\'vid\'series' ,
            'data_labels': {
                'value': True,
                'position': 'above'
            },
        })

        # Add a chart title and some axis labels.
        chart.set_title ({
            'name': vid,
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Calibri',
                'color': 'blue',
            },
        })

        chart.set_x_axis({
            'name': 'Compression Profile',
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Courier New',
                'color': '#92D050'
            },
            
        }),

        chart.set_y_axis({
            'name': 'Compression Ratio',
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Century',
                'color': 'red'
            },
            'num_font': {
                'bold': True,
                'italic': True,
                'underline': True,
                'color': '#7030A0',
            },
        })

        # Set an Excel chart style.
        chart.set_style(6)

        # Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset)
        worksheet.insert_chart('F2', chart)
       
    writer.save()
```

Comment: The creation of the string for the 'values' doesn't look right. Instead try the list syntax in `add_series()` like this: `'values': ['vid', 1, 2, last_row, 2],` See the XlsxWriter docs on [add_series](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series) for details.